# Is Jeremiah 2:3 an allusion to Leviticus 19:23?

Tags: law, leviticus, jeremiah, sacrifice

Leviticus 19:23 NIV

> 23 “‘When you enter the land and plant any kind of fruit tree, regard its fruit as forbidden.[b] For three years you are to consider it forbidden[c]; it must not be eaten. 24 In the fourth year all its fruit will be holy, an offering of praise to the Lord. 25 But in the fifth year you may eat its fruit. In this way your harvest will be increased. I am the Lord your Go

Jeremiah 2:3 NIV

> Israel was holy to the Lord,
>       the firstfruits of his harvest;
>   all who devoured her were held guilty,
>       and disaster overtook them,’”
>   declares the Lord.

Answer (score 2):

Is Jeremiah 2:3 an allusion to Leviticus 19:23?

**In short to your question the answer  is: NO**

Jeremiah 2:2-3 (NASB)

> 2 “Go and proclaim in the ears of Jerusalem, saying, ‘Thus says the
>   Lord, “I remember concerning you the [a]devotion of your youth, The
>   love of your betrothals, Your following after Me in the wilderness,
>   Through a land not sown. 3 “Israel was holy to the Lord,The first of
>   His harvest. All who ate of it became guilty; Evil came upon them,”
>   declares the Lord.’"

" The love of your betrothals," As a loving Husband, God cared for his people. Through his prophet Jeremiah, he reminded them of what their  relationship was at first,(when they came out of Egypt) saying: “(Vs 2)

> 2 “Go [Jeremiah] and proclaim in the ears of Jerusalem, saying, ‘Thus
>   says the Lord, “I remember concerning you the [a]devotion of your
>   youth, The love of your betrothals, Your following after Me in the
>   wilderness, Through a land not sown."

Israel  (the nation)was something holy to God the first fruits of his harvest, anyone who ate it became guilty.  (Vs 3) For example, when the Amalekites launched an unprovoked attack against Israel, under the command of Joshua God gave the Israelites a crushing victory over the Amalekites:

Exodus 17:8-13  (NASB)

Victory over the Amalekites.

> 8"Then Amalek came and fought against Israel at Rephidim. 9 So Moses
>   said to Joshua, “Choose men for us and go out, fight against Amalek.
>   Tomorrow I will station myself on the top of the hill with the staff
>   of God in my hand.” 10 Joshua did as Moses [a]told him, [b]and fought
>   against Amalek; and Moses, Aaron, and Hur went up to the top of the
>   hill. 11 So it came about when Moses held his hand up, that Israel
>   prevailed, and when he let his hand [c]down, Amalek prevailed. 12 But
>   Moses’ hands were heavy. Then they took a stone and put it under him,
>   and he sat on it; and Aaron and Hur supported his hands, one on one
>   side and one on the other. Thus his hands were steady until the
>   sunset. 13 So Joshua [d]overwhelmed Amalek and his people with the
>   edge of the sword."

Leviticus 19:23-25  (NASB)

Firstfruits, and Care for Poor. The firstfruits of each harvest were to be presented to God. (Leviticus 23:10, 11; Deuteronomy  26:1-4) The fruit of a tree was not to be gathered for personal use until its fifth year.  (Leviticus 19:23-25.)

Leviticus 19:23-25  (NASB)

> 23 ‘When you enter the land and plant all kinds of trees for food,
>   then you shall count their fruit as [a]forbidden. Three years it shall
>   be [b]forbidden to you; it shall not be eaten. 24 But in the fourth
>   year, all its fruit shall be holy, an offering of praise to the Lord.
>   25 In the fifth year, you are to eat of its fruit, that its yield may
>   increase for you; I am the Lord your God.